# xsd java class generating

Tags: java, xml, binding

Today I send someone a xsd file to generate java classes for me.
He said to me that nothing is downloaded from the internet during the XML binding process.

I still can't believe that, because if I'm opening the .xsd file, there is not much in it.
For example:

```
 <xs:element name="Country">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is generating a java class named CountryDocument.java and is 179 lines of code long.
How is this process working?

I still believe that internet is used during the process, because there are openAPI urls in the xsd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is likely using JAXB or a similar framework:

> Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) allows Java developers to map Java classes to XML representations. JAXB provides two main features: the ability to marshal Java objects into XML and the inverse, i.e. to unmarshal XML back into Java objects. In other words, JAXB allows storing and retrieving data in memory in any XML format, without the need to implement a specific set of XML loading and saving routines for the program's class structure. It is similar to xsd.exe and XmlSerializer in the .NET Framework.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding

Comment: All code that is generated is coming from existing libraries?

Comment: @Jochem that would be my guess, yes. Though it's somewhat hard to tell for sure given the little information in your code question. Out of curiosity, why dont you just ask that "someone" who did it?

Comment: One guy in india did it and don't want to explain the process